# Не сохраняются email и username в настройках

Tags: git, intellij-idea

вопрос такой:
После установки гита делаю git config --global user.email и user.name
Далее git config --list и они там есть. После перезагрузки пропадают.
Получается что --global работает на один сеанс или как?
Проблема вылезла из-за того что в IDEA не могу ничего запушить, т.к она не видит name и email, а сама установить тоже не может.

Comment: запушить куда??

Comment: запушить на гитхаб

Comment: так а идея-то настроена на гитхаб? Токен там, то-сё... доступ к репозиторию имеется?

Comment: да, все есть. При попытке коммита справшивает name и email, а потом error

Comment: что за error-то?

Comment: can't set user name

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать приложение "GitHub Desktop" ([скачать тут](https://desktop.github.com/)).

В приложении вы не столкнетесь с такой проблемой.

Если вы уже решили работать через консоль, тогда могу посоветовать вам задать данные таким образом:

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

Подробнее вы можете узнать об этом [тут](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git).

Comment: Также вы можете исправить напрямую файл конфигурации git, но путь к нему я вам не подскажу, потому что у всех он разный.